# Getting a use a thread or sync_to_async error

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, websocket, async-await

So Im working on a Django web chat. I just switched my db structure to be able to support groupchats. I changed the code so far and Im struggling to figure out how to fix the following error.

```
django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
```

And here's my websocket_connect from consumers.py

```
    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        print('connected', event)
        user = self.scope['user']
        print(user.online)
        threads = Thread.objects.filter(participant__user=user).prefetch_related()
        for thread in threads:
            chat_room = f'user_chatroom_{thread.id}'
            self.chat_room = chat_room
            await self.channel_layer.group_add(
                chat_room,
                self.channel_name
            )
        await self.send({
            'type': 'websocket.accept'
        })
```

I am happy for every answer!

I tried to change the threads variable but I cannot change this since I need it.

Answer (score 1):

As described in Django's documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/queries/#async-queries), running blocking synchronous queries code from asynchronous function might raise `SynchronousOnlyOperation` in order to not block up the event loop.

Some query methods have async version, like `get` has its async counterpart `aget`, but [there's no `afilter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/queries/#queryset-and-manager-methods) . However, you can [iterate over query objects using `async for`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/queries/#query-iteration). So, to iterate over the variable `threads` from your snippet, replace `for thread in threads`by `async for thread in threads`:

```py
    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        print('connected', event)
        user = self.scope['user']
        print(user.online)
        threads = Thread.objects.filter(participant__user=user).prefetch_related()
        async for thread in threads:  # async iteration
            chat_room = f'user_chatroom_{thread.id}'
            self.chat_room = chat_room
            await self.channel_layer.group_add(
                chat_room,
                self.channel_name
            )
        await self.send({
            'type': 'websocket.accept'
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it now(temporarily). It may not be the best solution but this is what helped for me.

```
import os

os.environ["DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE"] = "true"
```

Hope I could help, and correct me if there's a better solution.